# Android studio ConstraintLayout RTL issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am developing an RTL Android app configured in style.xml
put the code below in recyclerView item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.hosseinkurd.candle.utils.ui.BasicTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.hosseinkurd.candle.utils.ui.BasicTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_ask"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:text="9201"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txt_bid"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.hosseinkurd.candle.utils.ui.BasicTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_bid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:text="9548"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.hosseinkurd.candle.utils.ui.BasicTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:text="13:29:09"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_name" />

    <com.hosseinkurd.candle.utils.ui.BasicTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_low"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:text="کمترین: 9026"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/txt_time"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_name" />

    <com.hosseinkurd.candle.utils.ui.BasicTextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_high"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:text="بیشترین: 1025"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/txt_low"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

No roll or direction has changed at adapter file
but after scrolling, scrolled items' direction faced change!

There is no problem when 'txt_name' has a default value

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

use this in yout application class

```
<application....
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

Comment: I need to set android:supportsRtl="true"